# Add file links and attachment in evopdf: where can find HtmlToPdfConverter related classes?

Tags: c#, evopdf

I am using evopdf converter of version 4.6.0.0, and I want to add file links and attachment in my pdf document.
As suggested method in demo, they use HtmlToPdfConverter class to accomplice this functionality.
Link is http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/File_Links_Attachments/Create_File_Links_and_Atachments.aspx
But I am unable to find any class named as  ‘HtmlToPdfConverter’ and ‘HtmlElementsMappingOptions.HtmlElementsMappingResult.GetElementByMappingId()’ function.
Please help me to achieve this functionality or suggest me other way to achieve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo is using the latest features, API classes and methods from version 5 and later. In version 4 the class you can use is PdfConverter. You can download the latest version of the html to pdf converter from http://www.evopdf.com/download.aspx page.